# Can't get a telephone keyboard for input in iPad

Tags: html, ipad, keyboard, html-input

I'm trying to set the input tag with type that will cause the virtual keyboard to be opened in telephone mode, like this example:
[Telephone keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYDIx.png)

I've tried using `type="tel"` but it's opens the full numeric keyboard (with the symbols), the same while using `type="number"` along with `pattern="[0-9]*"` or `[/d]*`

I'm afraid that iPad doesn't have this type of keyboard...

Is there anyway to do it on iPad?

Comment: afraid! you cannot change the input layout of the keyboard for iPad.

Comment: Which browser did you tested your code on ? According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-email-tel-url) Opera mini (= iPad ?) doesn't support this kind of input.

Comment: @Zeratops I'm trying this on Safari and Chrome, it's looks like the telephone keyboard doesnt exists in iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the telephone keyboard is not supported by ipad.